# Jersey getting template path

Tags: java, filter, jersey, uri

Im using Jersey 2 and I want to get the URI template.
The reason is that Im creating an auth system that validates based on the URI. I managed to work:

```
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequest) throws IOException {

        String method = containerRequest.getMethod();
        String uri = containerRequest.getUriInfo().getPath();
    }
```

The problem is that **getPath** returns something like:

```
/companies/1
```

And I want it to return

```
/companies/{id}
```

Which is how I declared with:

```
@Path("{id}")
```

thank you

**EDIT** I thought I found it here:

```
@Context
private ExtendedUriInfo uriInfo;

//...
Resource matchedModelResource = uriInfo.getMatchedModelResource();
System.out.println(matchedModelResource.getPathPattern().getTemplate().getTemplate());
```

buut guess what? `matchedModelResource` is null.

Also, this:

```
List<UriTemplate> matchedTemplates = uriInfo.getMatchedTemplates();
```

Returns an Empty List of UriTemplate. :(
Why are the data not beeing set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. So the answer is to use:

```
 uriInfo.getMatchedTemplates();
```

Where `uriInfo` is actually `ExtendedUriInfo`.

This is the code I've made to get the correct syntax:

```
    List<UriTemplate> matchedTemplates = uriInfo.getMatchedTemplates();

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = matchedTemplates.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        builder.append(matchedTemplates.get(i).getTemplate().substring(1));
    }

    System.out.println("Permission is: " + builder.toString());
   // Prints:
   // Permission is: sig/companies/{id}
```

The reason the data was null or empty before is because I had an @PreMatching annotation in my filter class. Please dont ask why.

Hope this helps someone.